# Using scanf to output a standard logistic function of x?

Tags: c, scanf

I need to create a code that prompts someone to enter one floating point number, and output the value of the standard logistic function applied to the input number using scanf.

The logistic function is defined as:

```
                     L

 f(x) = ----------------------

           1 + e^(-k(x - x0))
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
float number;
 printf("Enter an integer: ");
  scanf("%f",&number);
}
```

So my question is what code can I write in order to have the program output the correct value? I think most importantly how do I incorporate the logistic function into the code? All variables should be declared as float. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: what are the values of `x0` and `k`? this is a nice exercise to learn c.......

Comment: @rioV8 x0= 0 and k= 1

Comment: Do you know how to write expressions in C? If not, you probably need to review the basics. Exactly which part are you stuck on? You might find the [`exp()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/exp) function useful.

Answer (score 0):

Just write a function that does the computation and call it as done in the code given below. Hope it serves your purpose.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>


float logistic(float x, float x0, float k)
{

    return (1 / ( 1 - exp(-k * ( x - x0)))) ;
}

int main()
{
    float number;
    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%f",&number);
   /* Let x0= 1.0 and  k= 2.0 for simplicity */
   /* You can change it whenever you want */
   float x0= 1.0, k= 2.0;

   printf(" Logistic value is %f ",logistic(number, x0 , k) );
}
```

Thanks guys for you suggestions.

Comment: You are welcome @Ryan James. Could you please accept the answer if you found it helpful?

Comment: why do you need so many temp assignments? It can all be done in **one** simple return statement

Comment: Yeah, I could have done it but I didn't want to make it look complicated for you and also for the people who may look at it in future.

Comment: @AkhileshPandey I don't see how an expression like that is complicated when its just an implementation of the logistic function which the OP obviously knows. If anything, your `temp` variable actually makes stuff more complicated as it's hard to see the original expression.

Comment: Okay fine then I will change it, that's not a big issue. Thanks @ Fei Xiang

Comment: there is no need to wrap the whole expression in `()`